# Cassandra CQL: query based on a field in a user defined type

Tags: cassandra, cql

I have a table created as follows

`CREATE TABLE users (user_id int, user_fname text, user_lname text, PRIMARY KEY (user_id));`

I then add another column to the table:

`CREATE TYPE traits (birth_year int, marital_status text, height float);`

Adding it to the table:

`ALTER TABLE users ADD user_traits FROZEN<traits>;`

I want to run a query which returns the names of all users who are single, however I'm unsure how to accomplish this as I am filtering on a field within a user defined type.

This is what I have:

`SELECT user_fname, user_lname FROM users WHERE user_traits.marital_status = 'Single' ALLOW FILTERING;`

However, this code returns an error when I run. Is this query possible to execute in Cassandra CQL?

Answer (score 1):

Query by the UDT field is supported only in [DSE Search](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.0/cql/cql/cql_using/search_index/tupleUDTqueryExamples.html), and maybe will be supported in the new implementation of the secondary indexes, but it's in the future.

You're making one big mistake by trying to use Cassandra as "traditional" database. You're missing the main piece here - table structure is selected based on queries, not queries are based on the table structure.  So if you need to search by martial status, it should be the primary key (although it would be a separate problem then, as it's low cardinality field).

As I mentioned in the [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64220223/cassandra-filtering-based-one-specific-value-in-a-set/64222358#64222358), you need to reconsider the use of Cassandra if you're using it this way, or completely change the approach to the problem.  I recommend you to take DS220 course on [DataStax Academy](https://academy.datastax.com/) to learn about data modelling for Cassandra - this will save you a lot of time.  Also, consider obtaining the 3rd edition of "Cassandra. The Definitive Guide" book that is [freely available from the DataStax site](https://www.datastax.com/resources/ebook/oreilly-cassandra-definitive-guide).